# Why does PyQt6 make Leaflet so slow with 1000 markers?

Tags: leaflet, pyqt6

I rewrote my old PyQt4 app that used Google Maps to a PyQt6 app that uses Open Street Maps and Leaflet. In my app I create about 1000 markers and call `myqwebengineview.page().runJavaScript` with simple commands such as `panTo` or `setIcon`. The new version is much slower - it takes 1-3 seconds for a couple of such commands to run. I made a self-contained script below:

```html
<!-- random_markers.html --> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>
    
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/python-visualization/folium/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.min.css"/>
    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #detections_map {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
                .leaflet-container { font-size: 1rem; }
            </style>
        
</head>
<body>
    
    
            <div class="folium-map" id="detections_map" ></div>
        
</body>
<script>
    
    
            var detections_map = L.map(
                "detections_map",
                {
                    center: [37.7749,-122.4194],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 13,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );

            var redIcon = new L.Icon({
                  iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png',
            });

            var detections_map_tile_layer = L.tileLayer(
                "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                {"attribution": "Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eODbL\u003c/a\u003e.", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            ).addTo(detections_map);

            // Define the bounds of San Francisco
            var bounds = L.latLngBounds(
              L.latLng(37.7081, -122.5136), // Southwest corner
              L.latLng(37.8324, -122.3569)  // Northeast corner
            );

            // Create an array to hold all the markers
            var all_markers = [];

            // Add 1000 markers with random locations in San Francisco
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
              var lat = bounds.getSouth() + Math.random() * (bounds.getNorth() - bounds.getSouth());
              var lng = bounds.getWest() + Math.random() * (bounds.getEast() - bounds.getWest());
              var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(detections_map);
              marker.bindTooltip(
                  '<div>' + i + '</div>',
                  {'sticky': true}
                );

              all_markers.push(marker);
            }

 
</script>
</html>
```

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import random
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        #self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
        #self.browser.setHtml("<html><body><h1>Hello World... Hello World</h1></body></html>")
        button = QPushButton("Random point")
        button.clicked.connect(self.random_point)
        self.toolbar=QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(Qt.ToolBarArea.BottomToolBarArea, self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.addWidget(button)
        self.browser.setHtml(open("./random_markers.html","r").read())

    def random_point(self):
        i = random.randint(0,100);
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript(f"detections_map.panTo(all_markers[{i}].getLatLng())")
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript(f"all_markers[{i}].setIcon(redIcon)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()  # moved show outside main widget
    sys.exit(app.exec())   #  use app.exec instead of app.exec_
```

Meanwhile if I add the following two functions to the same Javascript script and run the page entirely in any browser (including the QWebEngineView), I get no lag at all:

```js
        //define the function that pans to a random marker
        function panToRandomMarker() {
          var randomMarker = all_markers[Math.floor(Math.random() * all_markers.length)];
          detections_map.panTo(randomMarker.getLatLng());
          randomMarker.setIcon(redIcon);
        };

        // Add the keydown event listener to the window
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
          if (event.code === 'Space') {
            panToRandomMarker();
          }
        });
```

System info:

```
Ubuntu 22.04
PyQt6==6.5.0
PyQt6-Qt6==6.5.0
PyQt6-sip==13.5.0
PyQt6-WebEngine==6.5.0
PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6==6.5.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update: after converting the same example to C++ there is no lag. So the problem seems to be with PyQt.